Caves and Caverns TV movie?
Way back when, my sister talked about a TV movie she saw which I missed called Caves and Caverns, about a group of students who play Dungeons and Dragons for real in the steam tunnels beneath their campus. Their Dungeon Master is a highly strung child genius who loses himself, thinking the game is reality. During the game he disappears into the city and people/police try to find him.
This may have been the pilot for a TV series or a standalone TV movie.
I've been trying to find it for decades but the closest I've come are a two books. The Dungeon Master (1984) by William Dear, a true story about James Dallas Egbert III, which I think is the story I'm searching for. Mazes and Monsters (1981) by Rona Jaffe was made into a film (1982) starring Tom Hanks, based on the Egbert story but using caves.

That sounds a lot like the infamous Mazes and Monsters, which despite dealing with the alleged effects of fantasy role-playing games, is not really fantasy itself.

@Adamant I agree: larping D&D in tunnels sounds exactly like that.

IMDB has nothing relevant for "Caves and Caverns".  "Mazes and Monsters" is the likely answer.

I’m voting to close this question because the work in question seems to be about the game of D&D (as played in the real world), but it has no actual scifi or fantasy elements,.

The film "Mazes and Monsters" did have scenes inside a cave.

Voting to  reopen.  It is "about" fantasy and magic, even if it doesn't directly contain fantastical elements.  Haven't meta questions like this been allowed before?  I mean a recent question asked for an ID of a list of SF stories.  The list  does not in itself contain any SF elements, but the question was allowed.  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/287500/looking-for-mid-1980s-list-of-science-fiction-landmark-works  I'm sure we've had other meta questions.

Agreed about reopening; LARPing is a fannish activity and serial-numbers-filed-off-D&D is on-topic too.  Fans doing fannish things seems less off-topic than some other permissible topics.

@DavidW I'll accept the consensus, but if the answer is Mazes and Monsters, this isn't about fans doing fannish things but about a mentally ill person breaking down. It's a movie about pyschology, not about fannish things... (by the way and for what it's worth, the true story M&M is based on is not even about D&D either; the guy went into hiding and it had nothing to do with D&D, that was just bad journalism).

While you've discounted Mazes and Monsters, as the 1982 TV film adaptation of the eponymous book, it's a strong match.

Bound together by a desire to play "Mazes and Monsters," Robbie and his three college classmates decide to move the board game into the local legendary cavern.

These days, it's more well known for being an early Tom Hanks film. As I recall it (it's been a few years), they did not play in the steam tunnels, but in a nearby cave system. Robbie, the role played by Tom Hanks, loses himself in the character of Pardieu, the cleric, and travels to New York City, seeking the "two towers" he saw in a vision. After he stabs a mugger, seeing them as a monster, and plans to jump off of the South Tower of the Twin Towers to get back to the fantasy world, his friends find him, and convince him to stop and come with them based on the lore of the game. At the end of the film, he's on the grounds of his parents' estate, still stuck in his delusion, and they have one last game with him.
Trailer



And indeed, there's no actual fantasy aspect to it.

It was noted in the question, of course...

Ah. I misunderstood the reference, thinking that they'd only spotted the book.

As for the steam tunnels, the real-life incident that it was based on involved steam tunnels.

". At the end of the film, he's on the grounds of a mental asylum "  minor correction - actually his parents are taking care of him.
